# Dictionary to CSV file: Ordering of columns

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to export a list of dictionaries to a .csv file:

```
keys = hist[0].keys()
with open(file, 'wt') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, lineterminator='\n')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(hist)
```

I want the last key in the dictionary to be the first key in the column.

My list of dictionaries (hist) is:

```
[{'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.500409', 'Date': '2008-04-05'}, 
 {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.500409', 'Date': '2008-04-06'}, 
 {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.50331', 'Date': '2008-04-07'}, 
 {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.507939', 'Date': '2008-04-08'},
...
```

Which I got by:

```
for x in dates:
    l = {}
    for y in currs:
        try:
            m = exrates.get_exrates(x)[y]
        except KeyError:
            m = '-'
        l[y] = m
    l['Date'] = x
    hist.append(l)
```

How do I either change the ordering of the dictionary or change the ordering of the columns?

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered, so there is no "last" key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an OrderedDict if you want order and reverse:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

for x in dates:
    l = OrderedDict()
    for y in currs:
        try:
            m = exrates.get_exrates(x)[y]
        except KeyError:
            m = '-'
        l[y] = m
    l['Date'] = x
    hist.append(l)
```

To get the reverse order use reversed:

```
keys = list(reversed(list(hist[0].keys())))
print(keys)
```

If you just want to have the last key atthe front:

```
k = list(hist[0].keys())

keys = keys[-1] +  key[:-1]
print(keys)
```

You can also use a comprehension using `dict.get`:

```
for x in dates:
    l = OrderedDict((y, exrates.get_exrates(x).get(y, "-")) for y in currs)
    l['Date'] = x
    hist.append(l)
```

If you are going to supply the headers and don't want ordered dicts after just write as you go, presuming curr is a list you can use curr as the header adding Date:

```
import csv

with open(file, 'wt') as output_file:
    wr = csv.writer(output_file)
    wr.writerow(["Date"] + currs)
    for x in dates:
        row = [x] + [exrates.get_exrates(x).get(y, "-") for y in currs]
        wr.writerow(row)
```

The elements in curr are what you are using as the keys which are your headers so storing dicts is not needed if all you want to do is write the contents of `[exrates.get_exrates(x).get(y, "-") for y in currs]` with `x` written to the first column under Date.

Answer (score 6):

Hard code the header with the order you want.

```
keys = ['Date', 'RSD', 'GBP']
with open(file, 'wt') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys, lineterminator='\n')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(hist)
```

hard coding is preferred any time you want your csv to have a specific format.

Comment: What if you have 1000 columns?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with this quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) "The `fieldnames` parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the *order* in which values in the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method are written to the csvfile."

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  Either way the order must be decided upon somewhere.  Passing it to the `DictWriter` seems the right place to do it.  Using an `OrderedDict` is a heavy weight solution compared to this.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski if the op wants dicts in order then they need an ordereddict. If they dont plan on using the dicts later then they dont need to store dicts at all they can write as they iterate.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  My reading of "the last key in the dictionary to be the first key in the column" is that what matters is how the data appears in the text file.  Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - OP wants a certain order for at least one of the keys, so it might as well be explicit. It's explicit but obscure with an `ordereddict` where the order of adding to the dict is the order of the column. Updating that algorithm can change the csv in a non-obviuos way.

Comment: @tdelaney, if the OP does not want to have dicts ordered for later use then storing dicts is not needed at all then. Once curr is a list or any ordered container then the OP simply needs to write as they go.

Answer (score 1):

(If you're not averse to using `pandas`) You could do this by simply re-ordering the columns, look at the last step:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: x = [{'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.500409', 'Date': '2008-04-05'}, 
   ...:  {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.500409', 'Date': '2008-04-06'}, 
   ...:  {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.50331', 'Date': '2008-04-07'}, 
   ...:  {'RSD': '-', 'GBP': '0.507939', 'Date': '2008-04-08'},]

In [3]: pd.DataFrame(x)
Out[3]: 
         Date       GBP RSD
0  2008-04-05  0.500409   -
1  2008-04-06  0.500409   -
2  2008-04-07   0.50331   -
3  2008-04-08  0.507939   -

In [4]: y = pd.DataFrame(x)

In [5]: y = y[['RSD', 'GBP', 'Date']]

In [6]: y
Out[6]: 
  RSD       GBP        Date
0   -  0.500409  2008-04-05
1   -  0.500409  2008-04-06
2   -   0.50331  2008-04-07
3   -  0.507939  2008-04-08
```

Comment: I like pandas as much as the next guy, but the OP doesn't seem to be using it.